# How can I pass env vars to buster.js?

Tags: buster.js

I have a buster.js test. I need to pass some data to the test via an environment variable. How can I do this?

Comment: you mean when launching it at the command line?

Edit: I've just realized the question was made the '14. 
process.env.NODE_ENV;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean when launching it at the command line?

I've just realized the question was made the '14, anyway:
Run any node.js application along with the variable assignment, e.g:

`VARIABLE_NAME='FOO' buster-test file.js`

In the code:

`process.env.VARIABLE_NAME`;